# Shiro custom realm restrict simple auth to certain users

Tags: shiro

I'm using Shiro and have a custom realm.  My app has many users in a database, and I also want to support non-user process accounts for API access.  In my realm, I have implemented:

`public boolean supports(AuthenticationToken at)`

`protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken)`

`protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)`

This works great, we have a login form and process the UN/Password no problem.

I want to allow certain users to be able to use basic HTTP auth, and the rest to use form auth that is already working.  I can set the INI to allow either method but I don't see how to implement a check for the **type** of authentication used in the realm.

If I get a login attempt for a non-api user authenticated via HTTP headers, I want to reject the request.

How do I do this, write a filter and check for the HTTP header is the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to make this work:

- Add an "api" role to certain users
- Create another `Application` class and set its `ApplicationPath` to `/api` for the REST endpoints I wanted to expose
- Restricted the `/api` path to `authcBasic, role[api]` in the shiro.ini file

This works great.  Here are details: http://blog.mikeski.net/blog_post/470